# Proof that $(k+m)^2 \mod{n}$ is not injective

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

$M=K=C=\mathbb{Z}_n$

Lets say $n=10$

$E(k,m) = (k+m)^2 \mod{n}$

Proof that E is not injective (over $\mathbb{Z}_n$) for any key $k \in K$.

So what this means, is that any $n$ consecutive squares (for $k=0$: $0^2,1^2,...,9^2$ etc.) are never injective $\mod{n}$.

How can i prove that?

Comment: You are perhaps overlooking the fact that $k^2 \equiv (n-k)^2 \mod\; n$?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:

$(-1)^2=1^2$

................................